get unique id for unreal engine 5 multiplayer players
I am trying to get a custom unique id of the players in ue5 multiplayer.
Here is what I am doing:
in the editor I setup with 3 new windows clients and a dedicated server.
I create a session in one of them with advanced session plugin
then in the two others I find and join that session.
What I have tried:
in my custom playerstate I have added a replicated string property like this
UPROPERTY(Replicated, BlueprintReadOnly)
FString PS_UniqueStringId;
then in the game mode which run on the server only, I added a function to generate unique ids
UCLASS()
class AMY_GameMode : public AGameMode
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
public:
    UFUNCTION()
    FString GenerateUniquePlayerId();
    UFUNCTION()
    void ReleaseUniquePlayerId(const FString& IdToRelease);
    virtual void PostLogin(APlayerController* NewPlayer) override;
    virtual void Logout(AController* Exiting) override;
    virtual void EndPlay(const EEndPlayReason::Type EndPlayReason) override;
    virtual void SwapPlayerControllers(APlayerController* OldPC, APlayerController* NewPC) override;
private:
    
    TSet UsedPlayerIds;
    
};


FString AMY_GameMode::GenerateUniquePlayerId()
{
    FString NewId;
        do {
            NewId = FGuid::NewGuid().ToString();
        } while (UsedPlayerIds.Contains(NewId));
    
        UsedPlayerIds.Add(NewId);
        return NewId;
}

then on the postlogin and SwapPlayerControllers I get the playerstate and set it's PS_UniqueStringId property
void AMY_GameMode::PostLogin(APlayerController* NewPlayer)
{
    Super::PostLogin(NewPlayer);
    AMYPlayerState* PS = Cast(NewPlayer->GetPlayerState());
    if (PS)
    {
         
            PS->PS_UniqueStringId = GenerateUniquePlayerId();
            PS->ForceNetUpdate();
    }
    else
        PS->PS_UniqueStringId = "INVALID";
  
}


void AMY_GameMode::SwapPlayerControllers(APlayerController* OldPC, APlayerController* NewPC)
{
    Super::SwapPlayerControllers(OldPC, NewPC);
    if (OldPC && NewPC)
    {
        AMYPlayerState* OldPS = Cast(OldPC->GetPlayerState());
        AMYPlayerState* NewPS = Cast(NewPC->GetPlayerState());
        if (NewPS && OldPS && NewPS->PS_UniqueStringId.IsEmpty())
        {
            NewPS->PS_UniqueStringId = OldPS->PS_UniqueStringId;
            
        }
        else if (NewPS && NewPS->PS_UniqueStringId.IsEmpty())
        {
            NewPS->PS_UniqueStringId = GenerateUniquePlayerId();
            NewPS->ForceNetUpdate();
      
        }
 

    }
}

from my tests PS_UniqueStringId  is the same for two  clients and different of the last one sometimes all the ids are the same on each client,
but the three are different on the server which I get from the gamestate playerarray
please take a look on this
the yellow id's come from the local playerstate
and the blue ones from the gamestate playerarray


any idea on what's going on please, I have been fighting with this for a few days now.

Maybe the server can remember the active player IDs, and if by any chance a new player ID would be a duplicate, generate a new one until it is unique.

Also, are you sure that this isn't the line that cause your frustration: NewPS->PS_UniqueStringId = OldPS->PS_UniqueStringId;

How are you printing the local player state IDs?

i don't think since the id's in the playerarray are all diffents and have completely removed the SwapPlayerControllers method but got the same problem .
please look at my edited question with new screenshot

i have done some cleanup , and removed all the c++ functions of the gamemode except for generateuniqueid wich i made blueprint accessible .
now i have added a blueprint postlogin to generate the unique id from there , print it on the screen and assign it to the plasyerstate of the playercontroller .
the new unique id is generated correctly on the server and printed on the screen , but the variable wich is a replicated one on the client that have logged is not updated .

but there is some good news, when testing with the packaged game everything is fine somehow !
now how to make this possible for the editor windows too, because packaging the game everytime in the developpement phase is not an option .
i am using standalonegame window with playe as client in the editor options
